# Update '.well-known' folder to a Shopify store

Tags: shopify

New Shopify developer here.

I was asked to upload a file into the '.well-known' folder of the root domain, this used to be as simple as deploying a static file to the web server, however Shopify backend is managed, so I haven't figured out a way to make it working.

Anyone here experienced the same issue? Any tips?

Comment: I don't think is possible: https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/can-i-add-a-quot-well-known-security-txt-quot-to-my-shopify/m-p/890777

Comment: The last paragraph of [this answer](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product) suggests you "change your DNS to point to a server you own with the .well-known file loaded there, verify the domain with Apple and then change the record back to the Shopify CName; however, this does take your store off-line while you are performing this task." Seems hacky but it's an option.

Comment: @GenevièveM. The link seems to be wrong, can you please update the link for me? Thank you.

Comment: My bad ! Here it is: [Can I Add A "/.Well-Known/Security.Txt" To My Shopify Store?](https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/can-i-add-a-quot-well-known-security-txt-quot-to-my-shopify/m-p/1172307/highlight/true#M55552). A thread from the Shopify community forum.

Comment: @GenevièveM. Thanks! I read this link previously, it would be an option for those who uses it to validate the domain ownership with 3rd party. However, in my use case, I think that file needs to be there and can be accessed frequently...

Comment: Then I'm afraid that's not possible since Shopify doesn't offer such control over the server. An option could be to issue a ticket to the Shopify support team to see if they can upload the file for you.

Comment: @GenevièveM. Will do that, thanks!